# Difference between PiecewiseCubicZero and PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount

Tags: python, quantlib

I'm creating a PiecewiseCubicZerocurve and a PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount and obtaining the 1-year Zero rate from both curves. I expect my 1-year zero rate to be equal to my 1-year par rate.

I got two questions:

- Why does the zero rate differ for PiecewiseCubicZerocurve and
  PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount?
- Why is the 1-year zero rate not equal to the 1-year par rate?

I tried playing around with the number of business days and the convention. But that has not solved the problem so far.

```py
from QuantLib import *
today = Date(29, 1, 2019)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

convention = Actual365Fixed()

helpers = [OISRateHelper(2, Period(*tenor),
                           QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(rate)), Eonia())
             for rate, tenor in [(0.001, (1, Years)), (0.002, (2,Years))]]

curve1 = PiecewiseCubicZero(0, TARGET(), helpers, convention)
curve2 = PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, TARGET(), helpers, convention)

print('discount factor (zero)', curve1.discount(today + Period(1, Years)))
print('discount factor (discount)', curve2.discount(today + Period(1, Years)))
print('expected discount factor', 1/(1+0.001))
print('zero (zero)', curve1.zeroRate(today + Period(1, Years), convention, Annual))
print('zero (discount)', curve2.zeroRate(today + Period(1, Years), convention, Annual))
print('expected zero 0.1%')
```

Print statements output:

```
discount factor (zero) 0.9989871380405977
discount factor (discount) 0.9989954702856564
expected discount factor 0.9990009990009991
zero (zero) 0.101389 % Actual/365 (Fixed) Annual compounding
zero (discount) 0.100554 % Actual/365 (Fixed) Annual compounding
expected zero 0.1%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a matter of Business Day Convention and Settlement Days.

When using `convention = Actual360()`, which is standard for EONIA, and `0` settlementDays in the `OISRateHelper` (instead of `2`), I get the following ouput:

```
zero (zero) 0.099999 % Actual/360 Annual compounding
zero (discount) 0.099999 % Actual/360 Annual compounding
expected zero 0.1%
```

When using settlementDays > 0, you have to adjust your curves and your maturity date accordingly.

Comment: Thank you this fixed the problem. There still is a small rounding error, but I can live with that:
Calculated discount factor: 0.998987138 Expected discount factor: 0.999000999